# StructureMap ObjectFactory.TryGetInstance cannot resolve symbol error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, structuremap, structuremap3

I am getting "Cannot Resolve Symbol Error" for StructureMap 
ObjectFactory.TryGetInstance

But ObjectFactory.GetInstance is okay.

StructureMap Version 3.
Assembly include is "Using StructureMap;"
I am using this in an MVC 5 project.

Missing any other includes?'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ObjectFactory.Container.TryGetInstance is even better

Answer (score 4):

ObjectFactory.Container.Try/GetInstance() is now replaced by creating a Container instance and using the methods from it. ObjectFactory was an encapsulation of Container anyway, from what I read.

```
    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        // Previous way
        return serviceType.IsAbstract || serviceType.IsInterface ?
            ObjectFactory.Container.TryGetInstance(serviceType) :
            ObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance(serviceType);

        // New way
        Container container = new Container();
        return serviceType.IsAbstract || serviceType.IsInterface ?
            container.TryGetInstance(serviceType) :
            container.GetInstance(serviceType);
    }
```

Source:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/structuremap-users/S7nBib95zh0

Answer (score 1):

ObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance resolved this.

Answer (score 0):

As Vahid N.'s answer may be useful in [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/structuremap-users/S7nBib95zh0/M2726VjhVUgJ) :

> My version, produces a lazy loaded thread safe singleton, but your `Initialize` method is not thread safe. Try:

```
public static class StructureMapObjectFactory
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Container> _containerBuilder = new Lazy<Container>(() => new Container(), LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);

    public static IContainer Container
    {
        get { return _containerBuilder.Value; }
    }

    public static void Initialize<T>() where T : Registry, new()
    {
        Container.Configure(x =>
        {
            x.AddRegistry<T>();
        });
    }
}
```

And how to use :

```
DbContext dataContext = StructureMapObjectFactory.Container.TryGetInstance<DbContext>();
```